# Alternately taking elements from an array

Tags: ruby, array, iteration

Given the task of having to return an array that alternately takes elements from two arrays, what would be most Ruby way of completing the task? As of now, I have this code, but it doesn't feel very elegant.

```
def alternateTake (a, b)
  raise ArgumentError, "Unequal length" if a.length != b.length
  build = []
  (0..a.length-1).each do |x|
    build << (x.even? ? a[x] : b[x])
  end
  build
end
```

Example input & output:

```
method([1, 4, 3, 7], [1, 4, 2, 33]) = [1, 4, 3, 33]
method([98, 12, 41], [35, 22, 14]) = [98, 22, 41]
method([12, 33], [66, 45, 3]) = ERROR
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one-liner should be what you're looking for:

```
def alternate_take(xs, ys) 
  raise ArgumentError, "Unequal length" if xs.length != ys.length
  xs.zip(ys).map.with_index{|(x,y),i| i.even? ? x : y} 
end
```

### Follow Up

Tokland's answer to OP's followup about a solution without indexes is really clever.  Here's another variation, which I don't like as much as the index version, but it answers the question:

```
def alternate_take(xs, ys) 
  raise ArgumentError, "Unequal length" if xs.length != ys.length
  xs.zip(ys).reduce([]){|m,(x,y)| m + (m.size.even? ? [x] : [y])} 
end
```

Comment: Looks good. Some details: maybe use `unless` instead of `if`, give plural names to a and b (maybe: xs, ys) and unpack the pair `|(x,  y), idx|` ...

Comment: Is there any way to use iterators or something like that and avoid using indices?

Comment: @tokland, Both good suggestions, edited.

Comment: @Michael. A lot of ways, for example: `xs.zip(ys, [true, false].cycle).map { |x, y, take_x| take_x ? x : y }`. Not that there is anything wrong with using with_index.

Comment: Jonah, the second version is so horrible.. I don't think it's worth it. Children watching! :) There is nothing wrong with using with_index, it's not the same than accessing the array by indexes (which is indeed ugly).

Comment: @tokland, oh i agree.  the index is the right solution, and reduce is terrible here.  i was answering purely as an exercise.

Comment: @tokland, Better no index variation: `xs.zip(ys, [0, 1].cycle).map {|x| x[x.last]}`